# How to handle Signal inputs in the new control flow for conditional rendering in Angular 17.2?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular17, angular-signals

I'm struggeling with the control flow and a Signal Input in Angular 17.2.

I have this input in a component:

```
index = input<number|null>();
```

And I have this template. Since index can also be `0` I need to explcitly check for `null` and `undefined`:

```
@if (index() !== null && index() !== undefined) {
  <div appMyComponent [index]="index()!"></div>
}
```

Now I need `!` to make it work since `index()` can be `undefined` or `null`again, at least for the compiler.

I can't use `@if (index() !== null && index() !== undefined; as index) { }` since `index` would be a `boolean`.

**How to solve this correctly?**

Comment: Can't you do @if(index(); as number)? May be related to this issue:https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/49161

Comment: I think what you're describing is possible; or at least I'm not seeing the compiler issue you're seeing. There's no reason to have to null-forgive the signal inside a block that's explicitly checking for `null`. Here's a working StackBlitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-okhp9f?file=src%2Fparent.component.ts

Comment: I'd use `index() != null`. This closes both `null` and `undefined` checks in a concise way. Here, you have no choice but use `!`, because it's a function call. Technically speaking, there is nothing preventing JS from returning different values from two separate function calls. There is nothing wrong with using `!` except it not being pretty. Also, you might want to reconsider using `index` at all. Setting anything but 0 and -1 is considered to be a bad practice.

Comment: That's actually a good idea. So I'm going to use a transformator in the component where `index` is an optional input, converting `null` and `undefined` into `-1`. Then I can simply check `@if (index !== -1) { }`.

Comment: While using `-1` might work this time, when you're going to pass a number that could be any number, you'll be stuck. I have shared a different approach that would work for all the cases

Comment: @Sergey "Here, you have no choice but use !, because it's a function call" you're right on the function call, but you have another choice, see my answer. "Technically speaking, there is nothing preventing JS from returning different values from two separate function calls" Exactly! That's why we need an intermediate variable, and it's doable. "There is nothing wrong with using ! except it not being pretty" Disagree here. If you start using this all over the place, next time you're going to make a refactor in your app and move a block above its check by mistake, you'll have a runtime error.

Comment: I don't think having lots of nested `if`s with creating an object in place is a good solution. For moving things – tests exist. TS can only help preventing errors, it doesn't protect you e.g. from receiving an unexpected value and then working with it. Tests catch such cases.

Answer (score 2):

Lets start by understanding why when you do:

```js
@if (index() !== null && index() !== undefined) {
  <div appMyComponent [index]="index()!"></div>
}
```

You **have to** use `!`.

Your input is defined as such:

```js
index = input<number|null>();
```

In order to consume an input, you have to **call** it, because it is a function. It's exactly what you've done.

Do you always get a similar result when you call an impure function? No, it can be different. Hence why the compiler won't consider your 2 checks enough to then consider that the `index` you're passing as an input in your `@if` is not null.

It's simple to reproduce this in Typescript and see what the compiler tells us:

[image]

We clearly see here that the `value` is either `number`, `null` and can even be undefined (this is due to the fact that it's not a required input, so if it's not set at all, the value will be undefined).

Now, how do deal with this?

Let think about that solution in Typescript first and see how we can transpose that within the context of an angular template.

When calling a function can give you a `number | null | undefined`, if you want to make checks on the value and have your compiler know that from this point, you've got something that isn't `null` nor `undefined` and that therefore it's a number: Save it in a variable, and make the checks on that variable. Because you're not calling the function again which could give a different result, the compiler is then able to infer that the type is `number` after the checks:

[image]

Final step: How to transpose that solution to an Angular template?

Well, there's a little trick that it was possible to use the old syntax too (`*ngIf`). I wrote a [blog post](https://dev.to/maxime1992/angular-easily-extract-a-falsy-value-from-an-observable-using-the-async-pipe-112g) about it 4.5 years ago.

Here's the bottom line of it. The following is totally valid:

```html
<div
  *ngIf="{
    value1: value1$ | async,
    value2: value2$ | async,
    value3: value3$ | async
  } as data"
>
  {{ data.value1 }} {{ data.value2 }} {{ data.value3 }}
</div>
```

What's interesting about it, is that the `*ngIf` will always be true, as what it receives is an object. So you can store observable values into variables, wrap integers so that `*ngIf` doesn't consider the `0` as falsy, etc.

With the new `@if` syntax, it works the same. And here's in your case how you can achieve what you want:

```js
@if({ index: index() }; as data){
  @if(data.index != null){
    <sub-sub-component [index]="data.index"></sub-sub-component>
  }
}
```

Now that we call the `index` function only once, store it in a variable, make an assertion on that variable, Typescript is able to narrow down the type accordingly.

I have made a Stackblitz repro for you to play with where you'll be able to see the 2 experiments, one test with your current setup and the other with the one I just shared. Your code has a compiler error, the one I shared works fine: https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-wfvrva?file=src%2Fmain.ts